# Non-static desktop wallpaper in macOS

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, video, desktop, wallpaper

my question is exactly as it sounds. Is there anyway to make a "moving" or "non-static" desktop wallpaper in macOS. I'd like a loop or repeating video or something similar to what [Josh Fluke has in many of his videos](https://youtu.be/qv25aKhGANE). I'm quite experienced in python, java, apple script etc. and know of no solutions to this problem. I've also seen various tutorials that work for Windows but not Mac. Additionally, many tutorials on the subject *fake* video wallpapers by merely playing a video in the background or requiring an app to be open all the time (e.g. VLC)—and I'd definitely like to avoid apps that must appear in the task bar or occlude my desktop icons. Ideas?

Comment: I tried GIF, and it failed, shows a static picture. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can play any video as a Desktop wallpaper using VLC from the command line if you pass the option `--video-wallpaper` to the VLC executable. This will play the video behind your Desktop files. The VLC executable is located at `/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC`. I have that aliased to `vlc`, using:

`alias vlc='/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC'`

You can now play any video using:

`vlc --video-wallpaper movie.mp4`

This will cause the VLC application to be in your Dock. If you would like it to be hidden, follow the instructions in [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/349641/217983) answer, or copy the example below:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Add :LSUIElement bool true' /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

uses the native utility PlistBuddy to edit the `Info.plist` file in `/Applications/VLC.app/` so that VLC no longer appears in the Dock. If you would like to undo this so VLC will show up in the Dock again, use:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Delete :LSUIElement' /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

Comment: Thanks. I can play videos perfectly fine as the wallpaper, the only problem occurs when I attempt to hide it from the dock. When I ran `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Add :LSUIElement bool true' /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/Info.plist` the wallpaper stops working. But when I run `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Delete :LSUIElement bool true' /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/Info.plist` it starts working again

Comment: Are you running the command while VLC is open? If so, see if quitting VLC, then running the command before reopening.

Comment: I ran the command while VLC was both open and closed and it didn't work either time.

Comment: Is VLC permanently added to your Dock? I don't think VLC can be in the Dock while closed if you want to hide it.

Comment: Sorry, I phrased it wrong. If I completely quit and remove VLC from the dock, then add the Plist command, followed by creating the wallpaper, the wallpaper will not show up. The VLC is not pinned to my dock. I'm relatively experienced in programming and have eliminated the "obvious" reasons as to why it's not working as intended:)

Comment: I'm starting to think it may not be possible to play VLC wallpaper without the icon showing now that I've been working on it, but thanks:)

Comment: Huh I don't know what else to do then. It's definitely possible, since it worked for me on macOS 10.15.2 with VLC 3.0.8 Vetinari. I might try some of the other ways suggested [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/207939) if you want to mess around some more.